# HOW I can Translate from Sybase script To create Views and Indexes Structure

Tags: t-sql, plsql, oracle11g, sybase

I have the migrate from sybase to Oracle but the code is diferent in lógic and structure, how I Can pass this code to Oracle usung multiple Replace with converts and values after the replace

Here the example in Sybase

```
Create view dbo.View23 As Select
daftres.jicuenta
,STR_REPLACE (STR_REPLACE(STR_REPLACE(CDATYU.FSFILES,'|','/'),CHAR(10),NULL,CHAR(12),NULL AS CDATTYU_DSNOMICLIENT
,CDATTYU.Duregrimod
CONVERT (CHAR(8),CDATTY.DUYTUH,112)+CONVERT(CHAR(8),CDATTYU.dddultmo,108) As CDATTYU_JDEDFILE
LEFT JOIN CCLARO ON CDATTYU .JKDJDJJUN = SUBSTRING(CDATTYU.KSUHFHF.1.6)
WHERE CONVERT (DATE,CDSTYYU.JDJFJFJFJ 112)<CONVERT (date.'20210311',112)
```

Thanks

Comment: if the intention is to 'convert' from Sybase DDL/syntax to Oracle DDL/syntax, this probably isn't the right medium; you'll likely get farther looking for a DDL conversion tool ... perhaps a ER modelling tool that can convert between RDBMS products (eg, read Sybase DB structure into ER tool, then generate corresponding Oracle DB structures) ...

Comment: Hello @mark-fuso, I have the ddl only I cant install another tool to convert thats ddls, only I Have the sql developer this tool I have install without problems , I have all the ddls to create views  but the policy to install another software i Cant by intern policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To replace strings in strings Oracle uses [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/index.html).
- To convert strings into `date`s [`to_date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) can be used and [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) for the opposite.
- To get a character by its ordinal [`chr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CHR.html#GUID-35FEE007-D49C-4562-A904-041186AC8928) can be used.
- To get a substring of a string Oracle uses [`substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E).

Comment: hello to this scenario is replace with that options that mentioned,? Or is create different the script to create Views,?

Comment: @DavidMoisesSandoval: `CREATE VIEW` is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30 But there's very little to no difference to it in Oracle.

Comment: Hello@sticky bit ok let me check the document and review to translate the script , thanks